# Time travel short story, man tries to stop himself from killing family member

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

There was a short story, probably from the 1950's, about a man who goes to visit his grandfather or uncle, father etc. The man is confronted by a stranger, who tries to beat him up while walking to his grandfather's house.

Once he beats this stranger, he arrives at his grandfather's house and notices everything is different. After an argument the protagonist accidentally kills his grandfather. He then travels back in time to stop himself from killing the grandfather. He jumps out of a bush to stop himself and is subsequently beaten up and unable to prevent the killing.

I have searched all over Google. May have been originally published in "Amazing Stories" magazine.

Comment: Not sure I understand, but it seems to me this is **not** a "grandfather paradox" story? As I understand it, the man initially does **not** go back in time and visit his grandfather as a young man, but visits the old man in the present? And after the accidental killing (fistfight? gunshot?), **then** he somehow gets hold of a time machine, and tries to undue the damage?

Comment: @user14111 No, I also read this story (don't remember the title or where so can't post answer) but it was a mix of the grandfather paradox and possibly the concept that you can't change the past (which of course should be incompatible). He time travels back in time, kills his grandfather, then gets back in the time machine and travels back again to try and prevent it, and fails (time travel made him too scarred to recognize or something).  I never read Amazing stories, so I must have read a reprint in some old "Best of Sci Fi" anthologies.